# Seeking a textbook proof of a formula for the number of set partitions whose parts induce a given integer partition

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, integer-partitions, set-partition

Let $t \geq 1$ and $\pi$ be an integer partition of $t$.  Then the number of set partitions $Q$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,t\}$ for which the multiset $\{|q|:q \in Q\}=\pi$ is given by \[\frac{t!}{\prod_{i \geq 1} \big(i!^{s_i(\pi)} s_i(\pi)!\big)},\] where $s_i(\pi)$ denotes the number of parts $i$ in $\pi$.

> Question: Is there a book that contains a proof of this?

I'm looking to cite it in a paper and would prefer not to include a proof.  I attempted a search in Google books, but that didn't help too much.

A similar result is proved in "Combinatorics: topics, techniques, algorithms" by Peter Cameron (page 212), but has "permutation" instead of "set partition" and "cycle structure" instead of "integer partition".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the coefficients in the expansion of power-sum symmetric functions in terms of augmented monomial symmetric functions. I believe you will find a proof in:

Peter Doubilet. On the foundations of combinatorial theory. VII. Symmetric functions through the theory of distribution and occupancy. Studies in Appl. Math., 51:377–396, 1972.

See also MacMahon http://name.umdl.umich.edu/ABU9009.0001.001

Comment: Thanks for that.  From your answer, I was able to find it in:  _The theory of partitions_ George E. Andrews (Theorem 13.2).